# I tried to google but didn't find what is MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation in vb?

Tags: c#, vb.net

The line in vb

```
MsgBox("No input file selected please press the 'Add File' button.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error");
```

I did in c#

```
MessageBox.Show("No input file selected please press the Add File button.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error");
```

But not sure what the MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation should be.

Comment: Same code in VB. Use MessageBox.Show in place of MsgBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation` to show `Exclamation` icon on messagebox.

```
MessageBox.Show("YourMessage", "Your Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```